# Javascript Find Lowest Number and its key

Tags: javascript

So if I have `[2,3400,500,6,710]` I want to find the lowest which would be 2 and its key which would be 0.

Before I was using `Math.min.apply( Math, array )` but now I want to also get the key. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to deal with non–unique values, i.e. where the lowest value occurs at more than one index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.indexOf`

```
var array, min, index;
array = [2,3400,500,6,710];
min = Math.min.apply(null, array );
index = array.indexOf(min);
```

Answer (score 1):

xdazz's answer does the job, you can also do:

```
var a = [2, 3400, 500, 710];
var lowValue = a.concat().sort(function(a, b){return a - b})[0];
var lowIndex = a.indexOf(lowValue);
```

Note that `Array.prototype.indexOf` is ES5 so provide support for browsers that don't have it.

Comment: Yep, but create a copy of the array and sort it to find the minimum value is less efficient.

Comment: Probably the sort function is the most inefficient part, it would help if javascript saw the numbers and sorted them properly without it. Just wanted to do it another way. :-)